# How to form Appendix under the heading Appendices in ToC

Tags: sectioning, appendices, appendix

I want each appendix to be under the heading Appendices in the ToC.
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}
   \tableofcontents
   \chapter{CHAPTERR}
   \section{Sectionn}
    Some stuff.
   \chapter{CHAPTERRR}
   \section{Sectionnn}
    Other stuff.
\begin{appendices}
   \chapter{TABLESS}
   \section{DATA}
   \chapter{FIGURESS}
   \section{CODE}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

My output is [image]

But I want this:[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the command \addcontentline{toc} to add a line in the toc a the "part" level. It will work only if you have a document that accepts the "part" environment, which is the case here.

This is working :

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}
   \tableofcontents
   \chapter{CHAPTERR}
   \section{Sectionn}
    Some stuff.
   \chapter{CHAPTERRR}
   \section{Sectionnn}
    Other stuff.

    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendix}%
    \appendix

   \chapter{TABLESS}
   \section{DATA}
   \chapter{FIGURESS}
   \section{CODE}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the ‘Appendices’ heading, since you load `appendix`, you simply have the `[toc]` option.

Also, if you don't want the appendix sections in table of contents, you can change toc depth at the beginning of the `appendices` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\addappheadtotoc}{%
\appendixtocname}{%
\hspace{1.32em}\MakeUppercase{\appendixtocname}}{}{}

\begin{document}

   \tableofcontents
   \chapter{CHAPTERR}
   \section{Sectionn}
    Some stuff.
   \chapter{CHAPTERRR}
   \section{Sectionnn}
    Other stuff.
\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
   \chapter{TABLESS}
   \section{DATA}
   \chapter{FIGURESS}
   \section{CODE}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. But I want the word "Appendices" to be uppercase. Also, I want each Appendix to be indented under the heading "APPENDICES".

Comment: @oa-90: You want what?

Comment: I want the word "Appendices" in ToC to be uppercase. Also, I want each appendix (i.e., TABLESS, FIGURESS) to be under the heading "APPENDICES" in an indented style like in the second picure I posted.

Comment: The last point should be harder. I've posted a code which indents the word  APPENDICES, on the contrary. After all, appendices chapters are chapters and should be aligned with the other chapters, don't you agree?

Comment: Thanks! My thesis is supposed to be in this format. On the other hand, I added \usepackage[colorlinks=true,breaklinks]{hyperref} in my preamble. In this case, the code which you posted to make Appendices uppercase in ToC  gives an error. Do you have a solution for this issue?

Comment: You can not insert  `\xpatchcommand`, and replace it with `\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{\hspace{1.32em}APPENDICES}`. I don't think there are side effects (as to cross-references) , but I'm  not sure. Let me know if you meet any problem.